# Java hibernate get entity from OneToOne relation from where clause using hibernate session

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have java hibernate entity with OneToOne annotations, and my goal is to get entity by other hibernate entity.

```
@Entity
public class Pick {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int pid;

@OneToOne
private Match_soccer match;

@OneToOne
private Algo1 algo;

@Column(length = 100)
private String pick;

@Column(length = 5)
private double plimit;
.....
```

match entity:

```
@Entity
public class Match_soccer extends Match{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int mid;

private String status;
...
```

My goal is get picks where `match.status == null` using hibernate session. It is possible to get what I want using  session.criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write query as follow:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Pick as p JOIN fetch p.match where p.match.status is null");
List list = query.list();
```

This query will result all the Picks having match.status as null.

Comment: It is possible to do some, but using session.criteria ?